# Maven PITest Error "No plugin found for for prefix 'org.pitest' in the current project and in the plugin groups"

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, mutation-testing, pitest

I need to make a mutation test with PITest, but I'm having a hard time trying to install it via Maven, when I try to run PIT to execute mutations and the test case, I receive this error in the cmd:

> "No plugin found for for prefix 'org.pitest' in the current project
>   and in the plugin groups"

Can someone help me solve this problem, please?

My code:

```
package com.mateus;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Codigo {

    public boolean verify(String word){
        String regex = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_$]+$";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(word);
        if(word.substring(0, 1).matches("[0-9]")){
            return false;
        }
        return matcher.matches();
    }

}
```

My Tests:

```
package com.mateus;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

public class CodigoTest {
    Codigo c = new Codigo();
    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertEquals(true, c.verify("teste"));
    }
    @Test
    public void test2() {
        assertEquals(false, c.verify("1teste"));
    }
    @Test
    public void test3() {
        assertEquals(false, c.verify("tes@te"));
    }

}
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mateus</groupId>
  <artifactId>MavenMutacao</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13-rc-1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.pitest</groupId>
                <artifactId>pitest-maven</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <targetClasses>
                        <param>com.mateus*</param>
                    </targetClasses>
                    <targetTests>
                        <param>com.mateus*</param>
                    </targetTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

This is the error that appears on my cmd:

```
C:\Users\mateu\eclipse-workspace\MavenMutacao>mvn org.pitest:pitest maven:mutationCoverage
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml (20 kB at 14 kB/s)
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml (14 kB at 9.3 kB/s)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.303 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-11-19T16:39:59-02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'org.pitest' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\mateu\.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
```

Comment: You should try to use `mvn org.pitest:pitest-maven:mutationCoverage`. I would also use a more recent version of the pitest-maven plugin...1.4.10 ...

Comment: I wrote an article explaining how to use mutation test and PIT that may help you: https://pedrorijo.com/blog/intro-mutation/#mutation-testing-for-java

Comment: and if you want to see how to setup a real live project, with maven multi modules, take as an example this one: https://github.com/feedzai/feedzai-openml

Comment: thank you very much, @khmarbaise!! It worked with that command. Just one more question, I executed it and all worked just fine, but there is no file in my "target" folder to see a graphic interface of the results, any idea why?
@pedrorijo91

Comment: There should be somewhere an html file which contains the result usually in target/site ? Have you taken a look into it?

Comment: There is a folder "target" but there is nothing inside it, not even an html file. Maybe it is because all the mutants were killed? Or should the html be generated anyway?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the plugin like this.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.pitest</groupId>
    <artifactId>pitest-maven</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.10</version>
    <configuration>
        <targetClasses>
            <param>com.mateus*</param>
        </targetClasses>
        <targetTests>
            <param>com.mateus*</param>
        </targetTests>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

EIDT:
Instead of latest, use the version `1.4.10`
See the reference below link.

https://pitest.org/quickstart/maven/

It is also available in maven central, you can check this link.

https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.pitest/pitest-maven/1.4.10/maven-plugin

Comment: I just added the dependency as you said, but the same error appears, btw, the last version is 1.4.10, I fixed it but stays the same,  should I edit the question with the current pom.xml so you can see how it is now? I really need to make this work as soon as possible

Comment: Please post the complete pom.xml so that I can try at my end.

Comment: I just updated the answer, you can try now. Update the version `1.4.10` in place of latest

Comment: @DebadattaMishra Using maven plugin as a dependency is simply wrong. The issue is simply the wrong calling of the plugin on command line.

Comment: Could you tell me what is the right way to call it on command line? @khmarbaise

Comment: @khmarbaise Sir, I have updated the answer, actually the current version is `1.4.10`